# PHP equivalent for javascript escape/unescape

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

Let's say I have a string: **something**

When I escape it in JS I get this: **%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67**

so I can use this code in JS to decode it:

```
 document.write(unescape('%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67'));
```

I need the escape function in PHP which will do the same (will encode **something** to : **%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67**)

How to do that ?

Comment: *Escaping/encoding* !== "encryption". What's the purpose?

Comment: urlencode doesn't work? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: `escape('something') != '%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67'`

Comment: what you have there are the ascii hex values. in php you can use `chr()`/`ord()`

Comment: Try encodeURIComponent. That has a direct relative in PHP

Comment: `rawurlencode` is the `escape` equivalent

Answer (score 17):

**PHP:**

```
rawurlencode("your funky string");
```

**JS:**

> decodeURIComponent('your%20funky%20string');

Don't use `escape` as it is being deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

```
rawurldecode('%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67');
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what this does, why it is useful, etc. SO is about learning, not just answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

Some clarification first:

> Let's say I have a string: something
>   When I escape it in JS I get this:  %73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67

**That's wrong**. (Btw, the JS `escape()` function is deprecated. You should use `encodeURIComponent()` instead!)

> so I can use this code in JS to decode it:
>   document.write(unescape('%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67'));

Yep, this will write *"something"* to the document (as `escape()`, also `unescape()` is deprecated; use `decodeURIComponent()` instead).

---

To your question:

> I need the [snip] function in PHP which [snip] encode *something* to *%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67*

What you're looking for is the hexadecimal representation of charachters. So, to get the string *"%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67"* from the string *"something"*, you would need:

```
<?php
function stringToHex($string) {
    $hexString = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $hexString .= '%' . bin2hex($string[$i]);
    }
    return $hexString;
}

$hexString = stringToHex('something');
echo strtoupper($hexString); // %73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67
```

Backwards:

```
function hexToString($hexString) {
    return pack("H*" , str_replace('%', '', $hexString));
}

$string = hexToString('%73%6F%6D%65%74%68%69%6E%67');
echo $string; // something
```

Comment: `dechex(ord())` == `bin2hex`

Comment: Also update `hexToString()` function; much easier to use `pack()` on the string instead of iterating over hex values and use `chr(hexdec())` on each.