# Translate javascript string replace function to php

Tags: javascript, php

I found in [this](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/iframe-encoder/) site a very basic javascript function to encode text. Looking at the source code this is the string replacement code:

```
txtEscape = txtEscape.replace(/%/g,'@');
```

So the string `stackoverflow` becomes `@73@74@61@63@6B@6F@76@65@72@66@6C@6F@77`

I need a function that does the same elementary encryption in php, but I really don't understand what the `/%/g` does. I think in php the same function would be something like:

```
str_replace(/%/g,"@","stackoverflow");
```

But of course the `/%/g` doesn't work

Comment: `.replace(/%/g,'@');` only replaces `%` characters with `@`, so it does nothing for the `stackoverflow` string. You should post the rest of your js in order to trace down what's doing the trick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Replace a character

Indeed, the PHP function is `str_replace` (there are many functions for replacements). But, the `regex` expression is not the same :)

See official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

In your case, you want to replace a letter `%` by `@`.

`g` is a regex flag. And `//` are delimiter to activate the regex mode :)

> The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string. Without the g flag, it'll only test for the first.

```
<?php
echo str_replace('%', '@', '%73%74%61%63%6B%6F%76%65%72%66%6C%6F%77');
?>
```

In PHP, you can use flags with regex: `preg_replace` & cie.

## Escape

See this post: [PHP equivalent for javascript escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534674/php-equivalent-for-javascript-escape-unescape)
There are two functions `stringToHex` and `hexToString` to do what you want :)

Indeed, the site you provided use `espace` function to code the message:

```
document.write(unescape(str.replace(/@/g,'%')));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've tried your script but what it only replaces % with @ in a string. The script in the site replaces the letter 'a' with '@61', the symbol '%' with '@25' and so on, that's what the php script should do

Comment: I edited my previous reply with a solution for the escaping issue :)